# Модуль requests и re python

Tags: python

Даны два HTML-документа A и B.
Из A можно перейти в B за один переход, если в A есть ссылка на B, т. е. внутри A есть тег , возможно с дополнительными параметрами внутри тега.
Из A можно перейти в B за два перехода если существует такой документ C, что из A в C можно перейти за один переход и из C в B можно перейти за один переход.

В программе на вход подаются две строки, содержащие url двух документов A и B.
Выведите Yes, если из A в B можно перейти за два перехода, иначе выведите No.

Обратить внимание на то, что не все ссылки внутри HTML документа могут вести на существующие HTML документы.
Пример входа 1:

```
https://stepic.org/media/attachments/lesson/24472/sample0.html
https://stepic.org/media/attachments/lesson/24472/sample2.html
```

Пример выхода 1:
Yes

Пример входа 2:

```
https://stepic.org/media/attachments/lesson/24472/sample0.html
https://stepic.org/media/attachments/lesson/24472/sample1.html
```

Пример выхода 2:
No

Пример входа 3:

```
https://stepic.org/media/attachments/lesson/24472/sample1.html
https://stepic.org/media/attachments/lesson/24472/sample2.html
```

Пример выхода 3:
Yes

Что НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО в моем коде???

```
import requests, re
a=input()
b=input()
regex = (r'<a.+?href="([^"]+).+?a>')
resa = requests.get(a)
s=str(resa.text)
l = re.findall(regex, s)
x="No"
l1=[]
for i in l:
    if b in i:
       x='Yes'
print(x)
```

Comment: На мой взгляд, результат работы кода правильный, а в задачке примеры выхода некорректные.

Comment: Это задание из https://stepik.org/lesson/24471/step/6?unit=6780. Я тоже считаю, что я сделал правильно, но ПРОВЕРКА задания по этой ссылке НЕ ПРХОДИТ. Как сделать, чтобы проверка ПРОХОДИЛА?